# Use az tool to check when key vaults were created

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-cli

I am needing to check when a key vault (not a key) was created in Azure. Keyvault show does not seem to get me that info. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
az keyvault show --name
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call the REST API directly to get this functionality.  You can list resources of type Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults and use $expand=createdTime.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resources/list for more info.

Here is an example at subscription scope, but you can also do it at resource group scope if you know where your target Key Vault exists.

```
az rest --method GET --uri "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/1237f4d2-3dce-4b96-ad95-677f764e7123/resources?$expand=createdTime&$filter=resourceType eq 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults'&api-version=2020-06-01"

{
  "value": [
    {
      "createdTime": "2019-11-07T22:02:10.6437781Z",
      "id": "/subscriptions/1237f4d2-3dce-4b96-ad95-677f764e7123/resourceGroups/CSSAutomation-xxx/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/CSSAutomationVault-xxx",
      "location": "centralus",
      "name": "CSSAutomationVault-xxx",
      "resourceGroup": "CSSAutomation-xxx",
      "tags": {},
      "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults"
    },
    {
      "createdTime": "2019-11-04T14:57:25.8974771Z",
      "id": "/subscriptions/1237f4d2-3dce-4b96-ad95-677f764e7123/resourceGroups/rgKeyVault/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/KeyVaultTestyyy",
      "location": "northcentralus",
      "name": "KeyVaultTestyyy",
      "resourceGroup": "rgKeyVault",
      "tags": {},
      "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`az group deployment show`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/group/deployment?view=azure-cli-latest#az_group_deployment_show) to get the deployment of the keyvault in the resource group, the `timestamp` is that you want.

```
az group deployment show --name <keyvualt-name> --resource-group <resource-group-name>
```

[image]

**Note**: The command above just works for the keyvault created in the portal or via ARM template(need change the name parameter), if you use the powershell or cli command to create the keyvault, there is no deployment information in the group, the option is to use [`az monitor activity-log list`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/monitor/activity-log?view=azure-cli-latest#az_monitor_activity_log_list) to get the logs of your group, but the log is existing just for 90 days, and the operation will just appear as `Update Key vault`, so we could not know whether it’s `Create` or `Update` actually.